# How do I implement custom operator [] in swift

Tags: swift, custom-operator

I have written  a simple queue class in swift. It's implemented by an Array.
Now I want this performs more like built-in array.So I need to implement the `[]`operator but failed. Somebody help?

```
public class SimpleQueue<T : Any>
{
    private var frontCur = 0
    private var reuseCur = -1
    private var capacity = 0
    private var impl = [T]()

    public var count : Int
    {
        get
        {
            return impl.count - frontCur
        }
    }

    public func empty() -> Bool
    {
        return self.count == 0
    }

    public func size() -> Int
    {
        return impl.count
    }

    public func append(o : T)
    {
        if(frontCur > reuseCur && reuseCur >= 0)
        {
            impl[reuseCur] = o
            reuseCur++
        }
        else
        {
            impl.append(o)
        }
    }

    public func pop()
    {
        frontCur++
    }

    public func front() -> T
    {
        return impl[frontCur]
    }

    public postfix func [](index:Int) -> T //Error!!!!
    {
        return impl[index + frontCur]
    }
}

var x = SimpleQueue<Int>()
for index in 1...10{
    x.append(index)
}
print(x.count)
for index in 1...3{
    x.pop()
}
print(x.count,x.front(),x[2]) // x[2] Error!!!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html)

> Subscripts enable you to query instances of a type by writing one or
>   more values in square brackets after the instance name. Their syntax
>   is similar to both instance method syntax and computed property
>   syntax. You write subscript definitions with the subscript keyword,
>   and specify one or more input parameters and a return type, in the
>   same way as instance methods.

---

Subscript is not an operator. Just a method marked with the `subscript` keyword.

```
subscript (index:Int) -> T {
    return impl[index + frontCur]
}
```

[Read this:](http://www.codingexplorer.com/custom-subscripts-swift/)

```
class MyColl {

    private var someColl : [String] = []

    subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        get {
            return someColl[index]
        }
        set(value) {
            someColl[index] = value
        }
    }
}
```

[And read this:](http://nshipster.com/swift-collection-protocols/)

> Swift has a well-designed and expansive suite of built-in collection types. Beyond Array, Dictionary, and the brand new Set types, the standard library provides slices, lazy collections, repeated sequences, and more, all with a consistent interface and syntax for operations. A group of built-in collection protocols—SequenceType, CollectionType, and several others—act like the steps on a ladder. With each step up, a collection type gains more functionality within the language and the standard library.

Comment: I have another question. In c++, ```operator ()``` can also be overloaded.How can this be implemented in swift?

Comment: @AntiMoron then ask a new question. SO works best when the questions are about one issue.

Comment: For accuracy,according to Page 844 of "The swift programming language" from apple.Inc,operator in swift is those combinations which start with ```/  =  -  +  !  *  %  < >  &  |  ^  ~  ?``` and following by the characters above and unicode characters. Only ```Operators``` can be overloaded. For ```()``` can be implemented by closures.For ```{}```,customizing it is meaningless for it standing for code scopes and would increase parsing difficulty for compiler if was supported.

Comment: ```[]```,```()```,```{}``` are not operators. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @AntiMoron no problem at all. Using the right terms is crucial in finding solutions to your issues fast.